# Order of elements

Tags: ordering

I am designing a platform where the user can create items that are grouped into different categories.

Each category has an order for the items it contains.

During the process of creating an item, the user can choose the place in the order of that item within the category, by choosing a number in a dropdown, to select the place in the order they want for the new item.

By default, the place in the order of a new item is the last place, but the user should be able to choose any other place in the order.

For example, if there are 10 items, the user can select place number 5 for the new item, which will move the current item from place 5 to place 6, and all the items that come after will move one place (+1).

Do you think this will be clear to a regular user?

Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: The user may find it difficult to remember the other items already in the category, based on which they will have to select the place number. One option is to have a second step after creating, which shows the category items in order, and allows the user to select/enter the desired position, or drag-and-drop, etc.

Comment: Is the existing list present while the user is adding the new item? Is the new item entered in a text field? Where is the text field situated in relation to the list? Below? Modal?

Comment: Please add a visual mock of your context, and your current efforts so far. This makes it clearer, and has the potential for better answers and to be more valuable for the community as a whole. It's a good question, but the contextual details matter